# Zebra striping groups of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML and I'd like to zebra stripe the contents in groups of 3:

```
<ul id="item-order">

    <li class="thumbnail">Item 1</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 2</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 3</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 4</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 5</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 6</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 7</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 8</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 9</li>

</ul>
```

So I'd like to generate the following using jQuery:

```
<ul id="item-order">
    <li class="thumbnail stripe">Item 1</li>
    <li class="thumbnail stripe">Item 2</li>
    <li class="thumbnail stripe">Item 3</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 4</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 5</li>
    <li class="thumbnail">Item 6</li>
    <li class="thumbnail stripe">Item 7</li>
    <li class="thumbnail stripe">Item 8</li>
    <li class="thumbnail stripe">Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

How can I go about this? I have something like this in mind, but I'm not sure what to put in the if statement.

```
$('#item-order li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if (...) $(this).addClass('stripe');
});
```

Comment: I don't know jQuery well enough, is that `i` actually the index number? If so you want something like `(i / 3) % 2 == 0`. Otherwise you'll have to keep your own index counter.

Comment: `$('#item-order li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('red');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add it to the first 3 in sets of 6, you can use the modulus 6 operator.  If you want to start with stripes use the following:

```
$('#item-order li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if (i%6 <= 2) {
        $(this).addClass('stripe');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery has :odd and :even selectors, so you can just do:

```
$( '#item-order li:odd' ).addClass( 'odd' );
$( '#item-order li:even' ).addClass( 'even' );
```

EDIT, completely missed the point, this should be about what you want:

```
$('#item-order li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if( i % 6 <= 2 ) $(this).addClass('stripe');
});
```

Comment: He's not asking for odd and even. He's asking for groups of 3.